# MVC4 500 error rolemanager

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I do not have rolemanager enabled on my website and somehow I have gotten a 500 error talking about RoleManager which is very confusing and I been at it for 6 hours trying to figure out how to solve this error. This error first appeared when I logged into my website and then while being logged in I submitted I edited a form and the error popped up.

- Module RoleManager
- Notification AuthenticateRequest
- Handler ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
- Error Code   0x00000000
- Requested URL    http://www.mywebsite.com:80/
- Physical Path    E:\HostingSpaces\myspace\website.com\wwwroot
- Logon User   Anonymous**
- Logon Method Anonymous**

Thats what the 500 error says somehow I think this is maybe related to the web.config rolemanager which is for mines. This is my web.config anyone that has some suggestions please let me know my whole website is down because of this. Ohh and the website works great in visual developer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<configSections>
<section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myname" connectionString="mystring" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
 <appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
 </appSettings>

 <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".loog" loginUrl="~/Account/login" timeout="300" protection="All" path="/"   requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>

  <pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
   </namespaces>
   </pages>
 <roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="720" />
<httpModules>
  <remove name="RoleManager" />
  <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
</httpModules>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
</modules>
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>

 <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="###" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="###" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="###" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime> 
 <resizer>
 <plugins>
<add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
</plugins>
</resizer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it i do not know if this is an MVC 4 issue or not but if you disable RoleManager you must take an addition step and in your web.config put

```
   <appSettings>
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```